# Uniform convergence in measure space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $\mu(X)<\infty$. Suppose $f_n$ and $f$ are real-valued measurable functions on $X$ such that $f_n\rightarrow f$ almost everywhere. Prove that for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $A\subseteq X$ such that $\mu(A)<\epsilon$ and $f_n\rightarrow f$ **uniformly** on $X\backslash A$.

We can identify $B$ with $\mu(B)=0$ such that $f_n\rightarrow f$ doesn't hold, and consider $X'=X\backslash B$. So $f_n\rightarrow f$ on $X'$. I don't know what to do with the uniform part.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egorov%27s_theorem